# Ceil division of a numpy array

Tags: numpy

Ceil division of a numpy array

I want to divide a numpy array by 2 and return the ceilings values.
In other words, divide a value by two and round up.

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> np.ceil_divide(a, 2)
array([1, 1, 2, 2])
```

Comment: Can't you just do this? `np.ceil(a/2)`

Comment: `(a + 1) // 2` works too.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`numpy.ceil`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ceil.html):

```
out = np.ceil(a/2)
```

Output: `array([1., 1., 2., 2.])`

Or eventually:

```
out = np.ceil(a/2).astype(a.dtype)
```

Output: `array([1, 1, 2, 2])`